# User defined tabpage and anchors

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

I'm having a problem with a user defined TabPage and anchors. In my solution i want to used a template for a tabpage and add it multiple times based on users choice.

This is my template:

```
public class ATMTemplate : TabPage
{
    #region Fields
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public List<LogFile> LogFiles { get; set; }
    public GroupBox GroupFiles { get; set; }
    public DataGridView DGV_LogFiles { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public ATMTemplate(string directory, TabControl parent)
    {
        this.Text = "ATM TEST 2";

        this.Parent = parent;
        this.LogFiles = new List<LogFile>();
        this.GroupFiles = new GroupBox();
        this.DGV_LogFiles = new DataGridView();

        this.Controls.Add(this.GroupFiles);
        this.GroupFiles.Location = new Point(6, 6);
        this.GroupFiles.Text = "Log files:";
        this.GroupFiles.AutoSize = true;   
        this.GroupFiles.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top);
        
        this.GroupFiles.Controls.Add(this.DGV_LogFiles);
        this.DGV_LogFiles.Location = new Point(9, 18);
        this.DGV_LogFiles.AutoSize = true;
        this.DGV_LogFiles.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top);

        this.Invalidate();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    #endregion
}
```

And i create my tabpages with this:

```
        ATMTemplate atm = new ATMTemplate("", tc_ATMs);
```

As for now the "directory" part of the constructor isn't used. After i create my TabPage i get something like this:
[image]

After I click the fullscreen button it shows me this:

[image]

And when I come back to the windowed mode the controls don't shrink and I'm left with this:

[image]

Does anybody have a clue what I did wrong in the code ?

Comment: I guess mixing `AutoSize` and `Anchor` can be a problem. I'd try setting `AutoSize = false`, setting initial `Size` and `Location` according to the current `Size` of the `TabPage` and then setting the `Anchors`. Another possibility (for the case shown) could be to use `Dock = DockStyle.Top` or `DockStyle.Fill`.

Comment: I could use the Dock.Fill on the DataGridView but not on the GroupBox. I've set the GroupBox.AutoSize on false and nothing changed. Only setting the initial width of the groupbox helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried as I already commented and succeded with these changes:

```
this.GroupFiles.Location = new Point(6, 6);
this.GroupFiles.Size = this.Size - new Size(12, 12); // set initial size
this.GroupFiles.AutoSize = false; // and autosize to false
this.GroupFiles.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top);

// ...

// same thing for the grid view
this.DGV_LogFiles.Location = new Point(9, 18);
this.DGV_LogFiles.Size = this.GroupFiles.Size - new Size(18, 36);
this.DGV_LogFiles.AutoSize = false;
```

This gives the result you expect.